# Updating vscode doesn't show user code snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

Updating vscode doesn't show user code snippets.
If I move the cursor after entering the prefix, it appear only then.

Comment: Is this the same as [Visual Studio Code's recent update is disrupting autocompletion](/q/75340072)?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolved by following these steps:

1. Close Visual Studio Code.
2. Go to your user snippets folder, usually located at ~/.config/Code/User/snippets (for Linux), %APPDATA%\Code\User\snippets (for Windows) or ~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/snippets (for Mac).
3. Backup your user snippets folder by renaming it to something like snippets_backup.
4. Reopen Visual Studio Code.
5. Check if your user snippets are appearing now.

If the above steps don't solve the problem, you can try clearing the Visual Studio Code's cache:

1. Go to the Command Palette (Ctrl + Shift + P on Windows, or Cmd + Shift + P on Mac).
2. Type in "Developer: Delete Settings File".
3. Select the option "Developer: Delete Settings File" from the dropdown.
4. Confirm the deletion of the settings file by clicking on the "Yes" button.
5. Reopen Visual Studio Code.

These steps should resolve the issue with your user code snippets not appearing after updating Visual Studio Code.

Comment: There seems to be no command "Developer: Delete Settings File".
Instead, I cut the contents of the settings.json file for a while and found that it worked well.
However, I pasted the contents of settings.json back and it doesn't work again.

The contents of settings.json before and after the update would not have changed, but it is strange.